# Learning how to use canvas and create collision effect on falling particles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, collision-detection

I am currently learning how to use the  element and trying to create a collision effect on falling particles. I have written some code:

```js
"use strict";
//We select our canvas and get access to methods to draw on it
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
const title = document.querySelector("h1");
const titleClientRect = title.getBoundingClientRect();
const border = 3;
const padding = 15;
let titleHitbox = {
    x1: titleClientRect.x - border,
    y1: titleClientRect.y - border,
    x2: titleClientRect.x + titleClientRect.width - border,
    y2: titleClientRect.y + titleClientRect.height
};
console.log({ titleClientRect, titleHitbox });
//We set the width and height of the raster of the canvas
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
/**
 * Handles the window resize event by adjusting the canvas raster accordingly.
 * @returns {void}
 */
function handleWindowResize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    clearOldPaint();
    const resizedTitleClientRect = title.getBoundingClientRect();
    titleHitbox = {
        x1: resizedTitleClientRect.x - border,
        y1: resizedTitleClientRect.y - border,
        x2: resizedTitleClientRect.x + resizedTitleClientRect.width - border,
        y2: resizedTitleClientRect.y + resizedTitleClientRect.height
    };
}
//We resize the canvas whenever the user resizes the window of the browser
window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
/**
 * Clears the old paint on the canvas.
 * Useful on window resize to avoid showing a flashing canvas to the user.
 */
function clearOldPaint() {
    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
class Particle {
    constructor() {
        //Coordinates of the particle
        this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        //Size in pixels
        this.radius = 5;
        //X direction
        this.vectorX = Math.random() * 3 - 1.5;
        this.ORIGINAL_WEIGHT = 3;
        this.weight = 3;
    }
    update() {
        //We check if the particle hit the it on the Y axis (vertical side, specifically, the top)
        this.checkTopCollision();
        //We check if the particle hit the border of the title on the X axis (on the horizontal sides)
        this.checkSideCollision();
        this.y += this.weight;
        const hasNotReachedMaxVelocity = this.weight < 5;
        if (hasNotReachedMaxVelocity) {
            this.weight += 0.1;
        }
        //We add a X velocity to our particle
        this.x += this.vectorX;
        const overflowsHorizontally = this.x - this.radius <= 0 || this.x + this.radius >= canvas.width;
        if (overflowsHorizontally) {
            this.vectorX *= -1; // Reverse the x direction
        }
        // Check if the particle has reached the bottom edge of the canvas
        const bottomSideOverflow = this.y + this.radius >= canvas.height;
        if (bottomSideOverflow) {
            this.y = 0; // Reset the y direction
            this.weight = this.ORIGINAL_WEIGHT;
        }
    }
    checkTopCollision() {
        const isOnSameXPosition = this.x >= titleHitbox.x1 && this.x <= titleHitbox.x2;
        const hasTouchedTop = this.y + this.radius >= titleHitbox.y1;
        if (isOnSameXPosition && hasTouchedTop) {
            this.y -= 1;
            this.weight *= -0.7;
        }
    }
    checkSideCollision() {
        const isOnSameYPosition = this.y >= titleHitbox.y1 && this.y <= titleHitbox.y2;
        const hasTouchedLeftSide = this.x + this.radius >= titleHitbox.x1 &&
            this.x - this.radius <= titleHitbox.x1 + padding;
        const hasTouchedRightSide = this.x - this.radius <= titleHitbox.x2 &&
            this.x + this.radius >= titleHitbox.x2 - padding;
        if (isOnSameYPosition && hasTouchedLeftSide) {
            // this.x = titleHitbox.x1 - this.radius - border;
            this.vectorX *= -1;
        }
        else if (isOnSameYPosition && hasTouchedRightSide) {
            // this.x = titleHitbox.x2 + this.radius + border;
            this.vectorX *= -1;
        }
    }
    draw() {
        //We'll draw the particle
        canvasContext.fillStyle = "cyan";
        //We start creating the line (arcs are considered as lines)
        //And lines can be connected
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        //We set the x,y, radius, start and ending angle
        canvasContext.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        canvasContext.fill();
    }
}
class FallingEffect {
    constructor(particlesAmount) {
        this.particlesArray = [];
        this.particlesArray = [];
        this.particlesAmount = particlesAmount;
        this.initialize();
    }
    /**
     * Initializes the effect.
     * This method is responsible for any necessary initialization steps.
     * @private
     */
    initialize() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.particlesAmount; i++) {
            const particle = new Particle();
            this.particlesArray.push(particle);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Handles the particles of the effect.
     * This method is responsible for managing the particles.
     */
    animateParticles() {
        for (const particle of this.particlesArray) {
            particle.update();
            particle.draw();
        }
    }
}
const effectHandler = new FallingEffect(50);
function animateParticles() {
    effectHandler.animateParticles();
}
function animate() {
    //Draws a semi-transparent rectangle all over the canvas every frame
    redrawOnOldPaint();
    animateParticles();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
function redrawOnOldPaint() {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = `rgba(0,0,0, 10%)`;
    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --bg: white;
  --color: black;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --bg: black;
    --color: white;
  }
}
html {
  color-scheme: dark light;
}

body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 69420;
  color: var(--color);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 3vw;
  border: 3px solid currentColor;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<h1>Bouncing particles</h1>
```

## I believe I understand the logic behind collision detection

here's in my mind how:

- For vertical collision detection with the top: I check if the particle's x position is within the range of the x coords (x1, x2) of the title and if its y position is the same the title's initial y position. If it is, I adjust the y-coordinate slightly and reverse the particle's weight.
- For horizontal collision detection with the sides, I check if the particle's y position is within the range of the y coords (y1, y2) of the title and if the x position equals to either x1 or x2 of the title

If either condition is true, I reverse the particle's horizontal velocity.

But I am having trouble implementing it correctly. Can someone please help me identify and fix the issues in my code?

Comment: _"But I am having trouble implementing it correctly"_ - Can you give us more details about what this actually means. Please add any details of any debugging you have attempted.